# Rails Heroku CSS changes not appearing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production, precompile

I'm working on a Rails app with Heroku. Up until now, whenever I've made changes to the css and used `$ git push heroku`, the changes have automatically appeared in production. I must have disrupted something, though, because now css updates aren't appearing in production after pushing up to Heroku. The only workaround I've found is to use `$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile` before pushing up to heroku, but this is adding a .css file and a .css.gz file to the public/assets directory and updating a file there called .sprockets-manifest-5d988919b3309753adf7a8dsf7ads8708eb89e.json. This is really filling up the public/assets directory, which isn't what I want.

I'm using the rails_12factor gem in the production environment:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

Any ideas how to return to the old environment where I just had to push up to heroku and all the changes would apply automatically?

Comment: I think if you delete everything in public/assets Heroku will see that you don't have any compiled assets and will compile them when it makes the slug. Further reading https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: Easy as that! Did the trick. Thanks!